# How do I set a time limit for my Bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, postgresql

I am looking to add a Bootstrap 3 modal to my homepage. Currently, I have it set up so the admin can log in and add a message if for example, the office is closed that day.

The modal is working fine and pulling the message from the DB. But I need to set a time limit on it. I do not want it to be up for over 24 hours and risk people thinking the office is closed a second day.

My code is as follows:

```
>while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($modal)){
     if($row['Timestamp'] <= $row['Timestamp'] + 24 * 3600)
     {
          //show modal here
      }
 }
```

I have my timestamp set up as date('Y-m-d H:i:s') to set the time of the created message.

I don't understand why I wouldnt be able to add hours to my timestamp. Is there a better way to set a time limit?

Comment: What do you mean `set a time limit on it`? You want the modal to appear until a specific time?

Comment: Yes. Only for about 24 hours

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answer as the best suitable for your question, especially if one of them solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your timestamp in database has the following format `Y-m-d H:i:s` (as per any timestamp save in MySQL), you can't add hours like you did.

Better to do like so (untested code):

```
$oneDayFromNow = strtotime($row['Timestamp']) + 24 * 3600;
$oneDayFromNow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $oneDayFromNow);
```

Therefore, you have your date in the future. You can do your comparison with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your current conditional statement will always be false - a date will never be less than or equal to its-self plus a day.

You need to compare to the current timestamp:

```
if($row['Timestamp'] <= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 days')))
{
      //show modal here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I didn't exactly get the suggestions to work but they got me thinking. Here is how I solved the problem:

```
$date1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date2 = strtotime($row['Timestamp']);
$interval = $date1 - $date2;
If($interval <= 24 * 3600) {
    //modal here
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way but it works. Thank you for the help.